# Setting up boot loader (ubuntu and Win7)

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, windows-7

I have two physical drives. One of them contains my ubuntu (14.04) which I am using currently and the other one comes from different PC and has Win7 on board. My question is: is it possible to place these to drives in one PC and somehow setup boot loader, so I can use both ubuntu and win7 on the same machine? If so, could You provide any links/tutorials that will lead me to a sollution?
The point is, I need to have both these systems and I'm not eager to buy seperate hardware to use the other one.
I don't need any access to other system's drive, I think it would be better to deny such access, so nothing could be messed up by unexperienced user.

Comment: Just as a side note. If windows was installed onto the hard drive while the hard drive was connected to a different motherboard, the windows environment will refuse to function.

Comment: @Miphix I'm curious. What about the method descibed [here](http://lifehacker.com/how-to-run-a-portable-version-of-windows-from-a-usb-dri-1565509124).

Comment: @prakharsingh95 It sounds to me that you just want to have windows available. I can expand on how the W.T.G. works, or you can detail your precise goals and I can give you a list of options that can possibly be easier for you as a new Linux admin.

Comment: @Miphix, the hard drive created that way will work on different PCs.

Comment: @prakharsingh95 Well, than in that case shell out a few bucks to buy yourself windows 8 enterprise and a 'certified' usb key and you're off to the races.

Answer (score 0):

yes, not an expert on this but i'm assuming that the after plugging in both drives on your PC in order for you to be able to dual boot you only need update your Mbr or grub to reflect that you have two drives with boot-able Os plugged in order to do this I recommend you install Boot- Repair on your Linux Os and follow the tutorial provided by this link "https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair" to add the drive to your Grub.